# How to properly setup activities in a Masstransit statemachine saga?

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

I've been fighting a lot with this problem for a couple of days, but cannot find a way that actually works.

My scenario is that I have a state machine saga where I want to do stuff in the same transaction (Entity Framework) as the saga is running in, so that the state and business things goes together.

Now, I've understood that the state machine itself should not have any dependencies, and hence there's this `Activity(x => x.OfInstanceType<MyActivity>)` activity that can be added which is resolved from the DI container and can have whatever dependencies (services etc) in it. So far so good...

My problem is that whatever I execute in the activity I just cannot get it to work as it should. It gets resolved from the container and the `Execute` method is called, but then it somehow just quits.
It appears there's some exception thrown, but that apparently doesn't bubble up to the test harness.

I'm using Microsofts' dotnet core Dependency Injection library.

Here's some code

```cs
public class MyStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<SagaInstance>
{
    public MyStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(instance => instance.CurrentState);

        Event(() => Start, x => x.CorrelateBy(saga => saga.CorrelationId, context => context.Message.CorrelationId));

        Initially(
            When(Start)
                .Activity(c => c.OfType<MyActivity>())
                .TransitionTo(Running)
                .Publish(new Started())
        );
    }   

    Event<Run> Start { get; set;} 
    State Running { get; set; }
}

public class MyActivity : Activity<SagaInstance, Run>
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;
    public MyActivity(IMyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<SagaInstance, Run> context, Behavior<SagaInstance, Run> next)
    {   
        //throw new Exception("BOO"); // uncommenting this line doesn't throw anywhere
        _service.DoThatThing();
        await next.Execute(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

[Fact]
public async Task RunMessageSent_NonexistingSaga_StateIsRunning()
{
    var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
    var machine = new MyStateMachine();

    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    collection.AddMassTransit();
    collection.RegisterInMemorySagaRepository<SagaInstance>();
    collection.RegisterSagaStateMachine<MyStateMachine, SagaInstance>();
    collection.AddScoped<MyActivity>();
    collection.AddScoped<MyService>();

    var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

    harness.OnConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint += cfg => cfg.StateMachineSaga(machine, provider);

    await harness.Start();

    try
    {
        var guid = CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        await harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new Run({CorrelationId = guid}));

        var repo = provider.GetService<ISagaRepository<SagaInstance>>() as InMemorySagaRepository<SagaInstance>;
        var saga = await repo.ShouldContainSaga(s => s.Serial == serial, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Assert.NotNull(saga);
        // this Equal fails saying the saga is in state Initial
        Assert.Equal(machine.Running.Name, repo[saga.Value].Instance.CurrentState);
    }
    finally
    {
        await harness.Stop();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running on dotnet core 2.1 and after a lot of googling and browsing through the Masstransit repo I realized that there are better APIs for the Dependency Injection framework in the latest (5.3) Masstransit, which I didn't want to upgrade to at first to avoid having to also upgrade the dotnet runtime dependency to 2.2.

After doing the upgrade I started realizing that there has to be some async problem as I sometime got it working randomly. Then I realized that there was another method on the in mem repo, called `ShouldContainSagaInState`.

So by using this line instead, I got it working!

```cs
var saga = await repo.ShouldContainSagaInState(guid, machine, x => x.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Also running the code the way I intended to do, using the Request/Response pattern, potential exceptions are sent as Fault messages back to the caller. In the test harness this message is somehow available, but I haven't looked into a proper way to check it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple activity, registered it in IOC, used as You did, but have got the exception:

```
GreenPipes.PayloadNotFoundException: The payload was not found: Automatonymous.IStateMachineActivityFactory
   at GreenPipes.PipeExtensions.GetPayload[TPayload](PipeContext context)
   at Automatonymous.Activities.ContainerFactoryActivity`3.Automatonymous.Activity<TInstance,TData>.Execute(BehaviorContext`2 context, Behavior`2 next)
   at Automatonymous.Activities.DataConverterActivity`2.Automatonymous.Activity<TInstance>.Execute[T](BehaviorContext`2 context, Behavior`2 next)
   at Automatonymous.Behaviors.LastBehavior`1.Automatonymous.Behavior<TInstance>.Execute[T](BehaviorContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.States.StateMachineState`1.Automatonymous.State<TInstance>.Raise[T](EventContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.States.StateMachineState`1.Automatonymous.State<TInstance>.Raise[T](EventContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.Automatonymous.StateMachine<TInstance>.RaiseEvent[T](EventContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepository`1.MassTransit.Saga.ISagaRepository<TSaga>.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, ISagaPolicy`2 policy, IPipe`1 next)
```

I use Masstransit 5.1.5
What can be wrong?